# How to display text from a dataset in code.org?

Tags: code.org, app-lab

I am working on a Dungeons and Dragons app that will eventually show information from the D&D books. So I am trying to display the spell information from a dataset. I have tried using readRecords and updateScreen and it displays on the screen "undefined"

I would very much appreciate any helpful tips with this.
https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/VKNZ6xoJsy1ahETdh4R23_-Fs-JI3aF714hsoJqi3qg

Comment: Please add your code as codeblocks, not external links

Answer (score 0):

You would need to move `updateScreen(spellOptions, spellTime);` from line 87 into the `readRecords()` block on line 84. You would also need to set `spellTime` to `records[0].time`.

Here's what the code should look like from lines 84 to 87:

```
readRecords("Spells", {name: spellOptions}, function(records) {
  spellTime = records[0].spellTime;
  updateScreen(spellOptions, spellTime);
});
```